# removing xml comments without regex and lxml in python

Tags: python

I need help you guys to remove the xml comments using python...
-> tried many regex, its removing some part of text also which is not expected...
-> dont want to use lxml
-> please provide solution with any inbuilt functions or methods like minidom..

Xml data:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

</Context>
```

Desired output:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Actually i kept as html to insert the data, its an xml...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there are any existing APIs in `xml.dom` that removes the comments automatically. You can use a simple recursive function like the following to remove the comments -

```
import xml.dom.minidom as md
from xml.dom import Node
def removeComments(root):
    for c in root.childNodes[:]:
        if c.nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE:
            root.removeChild(c)
        elif c.nodeType in [Node.ELEMENT_NODE , Node.DOCUMENT_NODE]:
            removeComments(c)
```

Example of using this function -

```
>>> s= """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
... <!--
...   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
...   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
...   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
...   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
...   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
...   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
...
...       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
...
...   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
...   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
...   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
...   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
...   limitations under the License.
... -->
... <!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
... <Context>
...
...     <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
...     <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
...
...     <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
...     <!--
...     <Manager pathname="" />
...     -->
...
...     <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
...          on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
...     <!--
...     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
...     -->
...
... </Context>"""
>>>
>>> root = md.parseString(s)
>>> removeComments(root)
>>> print(root.toprettyxml())
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Context>





        <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>













</Context>
```

You can also strip out the newlines and tabs from `TEXT_NODE`s if you want to remove the extra newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get desired output using this... starting uncommented tag is missing...

this output i got earlier using regex also..but its not the desired one as uncommented thing is missing.

Thank you.

Comment: missing text is : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>